# Tooltip p:selectOneRadio for f:selectItem

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I wanna put a tooltip for each f:selectItem on my selectOneRadio, somenthing like:

```
<p:datatable data...>
 <p:selectOneRadio required="true" requiredMessage="Required"> 
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" title="msg 1"/>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" title="msg 2"/> 
 </p:selectOneRadio>
</p:datatable>
```

Any ideas or sugesttions?

Answer (score 0):

Use itemDescription for tooltip. Please try the following.

```
<p:datatable data...>
 <p:selectOneRadio required="true" requiredMessage="Required"> 
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" itemDescription="msg 1"/>
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" itemDescription="msg 2"/> 
 </p:selectOneRadio>
</p:datatable>
```

Comment: This is insufficient (custom renderer is needed). Moreover, if you can't answer from top of head but searched and found an answer, link/attribute it or vote as duplicate. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077